# Как получить выделенную строку таблицы?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Есть имя таблицы. Одна из строк выделена (помечена классом info).
Как найти номер этой строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понял, Вы хотите индекс строки с классом `info`. Для этого, можно использовать функцию [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

```js
alert($("tr.info").index());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class="info"><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: В вопросе допустил ошибку ... Помечена классом info, а не атрибутом... Сорри... Подредактируйте ответ, я вам поставлю решение

Comment: @sitev_ru Ничего страшного, я исправил.

Answer (score -1):

В table находится имя таблицы, тогда:

```
<code lang="html">
var index = $("#" + table + " tbody tr.info").index();
</code>
```

Comment: Или это ваш ответ? Так @Peter Olson вам ответил правильно.

Comment: tr[info] не работает, зато работает tr.info

Comment: Нажмите кнопку `Выполнить код` ниже ответа @Peter Olson и увидите как оно там не работает :P

Comment: В вопросе допустил ошибку ... Помечена классом info... Сорри